# How to join 2 attributes to create a name in Django model instance?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Subject(models.Model):
    level = models.CharField(choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, max_length=2)
    subject_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_seats = models.IntegerField()
    subject_details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject_img = models.ImageField()
```

I want to display each instance as level and then subject name. For example, if the instance has a `level` 'Advanced' and `subject_name` as 'Physics', I want the instance to be displayed as 'Advanced Physics'.

I have tried using **str** method but it shows `subject_name` is not defined:

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.level+ ''+ subject_name
```

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that `level` field takes in choices, as so:

```
LEVEL_CHOICES = (
    ('09', 'Class 9 O level'),
    ('10', 'Class 10 O level'),
    ('11', 'AS level'),
    ('12', 'A2 level'),
)
```

How do I display the data that is visible to human? ie. the ones on the right as the `level`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are attributes defined on the `self` object, so you implement this as:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.level + '' + self.subject_name
```

or you perhaps can use string formatting here:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.level}{self.subject_name}'
```

If you want to use the display value for the choice of `level`, you can call the `get_level_display` method:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_level_display() + '' + self.subject_name
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the field level takes in choices. Please check the edit

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to `self` to access `subject_name` as such:

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.level + ' ' + self.subject_name
```

or formatted via Python3:

```
def __str__(self):
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.level, self.subject_name)
```

and to get the human readable value, you can simply use the `.get_FOO_display()` method:

```
def __str__(self):
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.get_level_display(), self.subject_name)
```

> Model.get_FOO_display(): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

Comment: I forgot to mention that level takes in choices. Please check the edit!

Comment: @iscream Edited my answer to show how you can do that